# Who named Pan's character?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

So, I was wondering who decided to name the character Pan.

From what I know, she appears first in Dragon Ball GT, which isn't made by Akira Toriyama.

But we find her again in Dragon Ball Super.
So, did Toriyama use what was created by Dragon Ball GT's makers, or was he involved in the creation of Pan directly in GT ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pan appears for the first time in  the last chapter of the Dragon Ball manga, not in  GT

[image: ee]

She is below Son Gohan and Videl

So, unless an editor or  person close to Toriyama chose her  name, the author himself is who did it.

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Learn more about how it works in the [help].

Answer (score 1):

My guess is Toriyama-sensei, given his signature lack of imagination for names. Seriously, don't explore this names thing further or you'll end up disappointed.

Answer (score -1):

Anyway, it looks like he was involved during GT, so I guess, Toriyama did.

[How involved was Akira Toriyama in the production of Dragon Ball GT?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/361/how-involved-was-akira-toriyama-in-the-production-of-dragon-ball-gt)