# Why is DragonballGT not canon?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-gt

I've heard DragonballGT is not Canon, even though it was aired on TV years ago. Why isn't it canon?

Comment: Related: [How involved was Akira Toriyama in the production of Dragon Ball GT?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/361/2516), [Which parts of Dragon Ball GT do not follow the original Dragon Ball story?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/34368/2516)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an english speaking source to quote, but quoting and translating a spanish one,

> Dragon Ball GT is an alternate story to the main story, however, it
> wasnt made by Akira Toriyama

[Why Dragon Ball GT isnt canon](https://rpp.pe/cultura/asiapop/dragon-ball-por-que-saga-gt-no-es-considerada-canon-ag-noticia-1395194)

To summarize, Dragon Ball GT isnt canon because the creator of Dragon Ball wasnt directly involved on it, and its events conflict now with the main continuity and canon sequel which is Dragon Ball Super

Comment: The letter they're referring to is this: https://www.kanzenshuu.com/translations/dragon-book-gt-toriyama-intro/ . It's promotional material for a *Dragon Ball GT* DVD box, dating June 2005. What Toriyama meant by サイドストーリー, which reads *saidosutōrī* and has usually been translated in English as *side story*, has long been debated. I don't know if the Spanish translator has more information to back their *historia alterna* up. Be as it may, at the moment it certainly seems that the current production team of *Dragon Ball* does not feel compelled to avoid overwriting GT's plot.

Comment: @Gae.S. it turns out that the current production team (the one which made Dragon Ball Super) works based on ideas of Akira Toriyama, the last movie was also written by Akira Toriyama, so it's Akira Toriyama writting over Dragon Ball GT, which clearly he never considered part of the main continuity, since he didnt write it

Comment: Fair enough, I hope my research was appreciated. It should be noted that the current manga arc of DBS will be taking place right after the Cell-Max film, which in Toriyama's words was "right before" the events of Dragon Ball chapters 518-519. So at the moment he's possibly writing over environmental elements of GT, but not the events themselves. Ironically, some details of his own last three chapters have already been written over! :P

Comment: This has some links to interviews: https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/5lbbpl/toriyamas_own_statements_on_dragon_ball_canon/

Comment: RIP Toriyama, by the way https://en.dragon-ball-official.com/news/01_2499.html